# Comparing two Date values in ActionScript - possible to compare whole day values?

Tags: date, actionscript, comparison

I need to be able to compare the number of whole days between two dates in ActionScript, is this possible?

I'd like to test if one date is 7 days or less after today, and if so is it one day or less (if it's before today this also counts).

The workaround I have in place is using the .time part of the date field:

```
// Get the diffence between the current date and the due date
var dateDiff:Date = new Date();
dateDiff.setTime (dueDate.time - currentDate.time);
if (dateDiff.time < ( 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ))
    return "Date is within 1 day");
else if (dateDiff.time < ( 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ))
    return "Date is within 7 days");
```

As I say - this is only a workaround, I'd like a permanent solution to allow me to check the number of whole days between 2 dates. Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: duplicate of this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268770/as2-calculate-days-between-two-dates/726906

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var daysDifference:Number = Math.floor((dueDate.time-currentDate.time)/(1000*60*60*24));
if (daysDifference < 2)
   return "Date is within 1 day";
else if (daysDifference < 8)
   return "Date is within 7 days";
```